# how to know what a function is doing in python

Tags: python

I'm totally new in advanced python themes. A while ago check this (https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/markov_regression.html), and although I understand that you are defining your variables, I always wanted to see how `smoothed_marginal_probabilities` worked, but I don't know how to look for what this function does.

I apologize in advance if the question is very simple, but I am starting on this. regards!

Comment: Two things I can think of: 1) Check the source code, 2) Check the library's documentation

Answer (score 0):

In code editors like vscode or pycharm press control and click on that function. You will see what you asked for.

But if you mean a func that you see on the internet. The best way is reading their docs.